# Is Deadpool as "R-rated" in the comics as he is in the Deadpool movie?

Tags: marvel, adaptation-comparison, deadpool

From what I understand of the Deadpool movie, it involves lots of language, violence, and graphic nudity.

I've read a lot of Deadpool comics, and I only remember the violence. I don't remember any nudity or uncensored language.

So why is the movie being portrayed this way? Is it a deviation from the comic. Have I just read the wrong comics?

### Is comic Deadpool really as "R-rated" as movie Deadpool?

Comment: It stars Ryan Reynolds, so there’s a good chance even if the comics have absolutely no nudity whatsoever, adding some in is a great way to draw in more of an audience (hell, I’ve never even heard of Deadpool, and I’m going to see it just for that!). A bit of gratuitous, naked Ryan Reynolds is always popular.

Comment: It's not like Reynolds is exactly bashful...

Comment: I was really disappointed! That movie should not have had nudity or sex. I appreciate Ryan's attractiveness as much as the next girl but don't screw up comics! There are a lot of comic fans who are preteens or young teens who shouldn't be allowed to watch this movie. They are huge comic fans but because of all the unnecessary crap they won't be able to see it. Why would we exclude the next generation of comic creators and lovers? I thought it was ridiculous. I won't be watching a sequel if there is one.

Comment: @Carrie: it’s so difficult to find movie for pre-teens that are *just* really violent these days.

Comment: @user64575 Seriously, the nudity (which is how every human is born after all) and the sex (the product of which we all are) did bother you more than people getting their heads chopped off or getting bullets through their skulls? For me it would be the other way around if I thought about trying to prevent my kids from seeing anything traumatic. For me murder is bad, as well as violent killing, even in defence of self or others, whereas sex and nudity would not be a big deal for me... - could be a cultural thing though...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No. Deadpool the comic is not as adult themed as Deadpool (2016).

**Deadpool the comic is rated Parental Advisory.** [marvel.com](http://marvel.com/comics/series/16542/deadpool_2012_-_present)

That rating has been [described](http://headsup.boyslife.org/a-newbies-guide-to-comic-books/) as

> Appropriate for readers age 15 and older. May contain moderate violence, mild profanity, graphic imagery and/or suggestive themes.

**Deadpool (2016) is rated R.**

> Rated R, abundant harsh profanity, graphic sexual dialogue, graphic violence, a lot of nudity and sexuality. - [ericdsnider.com](http://www.ericdsnider.com/movies/deadpool/)

[A parent's guide to Deadpool](https://www.ksl.com/?sid=38443187&nid=1205) (in an admittedly conservative community):

> Not only does Deadpool like to destroy his enemies, but he likes to do it on screen. There is plenty of blood, gore and violence to really go around...
>
> The language is harsh and constant throughout the movie...
>
> The film includes full-frontal male and female nudity, a constant barrage of raunchy sex-related jokes and an extended sex scene that lasts several minutes and contains a few things I'm not totally comfortable mentioning here.

Comment: UK film Classification is "15" rather than "18"

Comment: http://www.bbfc.co.uk/releases/deadpool-2016

Comment: 16 in Brazil - http://cinema10.com.br/filme/deadpool

Comment: From the way people talk about it online, you'd think anything but a hard R rating would be an unacceptable deviation from the comic.

Comment: There were two Deadpool MAX series that were R-rated, but I don't *think* there was any full frontal nudity in them, which the movie has, so it's still "more" R-rated.

Comment: I don't recall full frontal male or female nudity.  I remember some boob and butt, that's all.

Answer (score 11):

#### Yes. While the comic has been considered PG, depending on when you read it and whose writing it, the comic book can be as violent and as random as depicted in the 2016 movie. Witness:

[image]

[image]

The sexual aspects are downplayed considerably with innuendo being as close as the comic gets to talking about sex, as a whole.

[image]

[image]

Thus, I would not recommend the comic for impressionable young minds unless they have been desensitized to random acts of violence beyond the normal fisticuffs of the comic genre.

Comment: +1 for the pictures. Not accepting as the OP kind of already acknowledged the violence, and only asked about everything else.

Comment: What are you talking about? I answered the question with the facts at hand. The comic CAN be as violent as the movie. It isn't always, but it certainly has the potential. Anyone who read the comic was going to be quite comfortable with the movie depiction: Gratuitous violence abounded.

Comment: To quote the OP: *I've read a lot of Deadpool comics, and I only remember the violence. I don't remember any nudity or uncensored language.*

Answer (score 1):

I have read every single issue of Deadpool, as well as every appearance he has had in the other titles... while nudity was not as graphic, show me one Marvel comic that is... same with the profanity. They were holding into a certain level that was not allowed in comics... however, this is a highly sexually active character, a character who blew his own brains out to avoid boring conversations, who got involved with a teenage prostitute... (age was not defined until after the fact, so statutory rape is a possibility)... who leaves pornography for children, who writes graffiti in blood....

Comment: This is a good answer, but we try to avoid confrontational posts. I edited out the bit bashing the people who want Deadpool to be less R-rated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which book you read.  The Deadpool MAX stuff is as R rated as the movie.  The rest of the books are as bad as you can get in the regular Marvel world, with lots of innuendo and grawlix.  He certainly has had sex with a number of Marvel characters, including Copy Cat, Domino and Siryn.

For me, a PG-13 version would have been untrue to the character, unless you actually bleeped out his speech, which would be silly.